# Contraposition and contradiction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I have some questions about mathematical logic.

1) About reasoning by contraposition :

If we have two predicates $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ on a set $A$, do we have the following equivalence between the following propositions :

$(\forall x \in A, P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow [(\forall x \in A, P(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall x \in A, Q(x))]$ ?

From that, when we say that we do a reasoning by contraposition, what do we do exactly :

$(\forall x \in A, \neg P(x) \Rightarrow \neg Q(x))$

or

$[(\forall x \in A, \neg Q(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall x \in A, \neg P(x))]$ ?

2) About reasoning by contradiction :

Again, if we have for example two predicates $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ on a set $A$, and if we have the proposition $(\forall x \in A, P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))$, when we do a proof by contradiction, what do we assume exactly :

$\neg (\forall x \in A, P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x \in A, P(x) \wedge \neg Q(x))$

or

$[\forall x \in A, \neg (P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))] \Leftrightarrow (\forall x \in A, P(x) \wedge \neg Q(x))$ ?

3) More generally :

If we have two predicates $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ on a set $A$, when we state : "$P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$", are we agree that we cannot assign the value "true" or the value "false" to this ?
In general, are we agree that (when we read that kind of notation in a book for example), we can understand : "$\forall x \in A, P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$" ?

Thank you for your future answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)** No, they are not equivalent. For example take $A$ to be $\mathbb N$ and $P(x)$ to mean "$x$ is odd" and $Q(x)$ to mean "$x$ is even".

Then $(\forall x\in A:P(x))$ and $(\forall x\in A:Q(x))$ are both false, and therefore $(\forall x\in A:P(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall x\in A:Q(x))$ is true.

But $(\forall x\in A: P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x))$ is false, because $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ is false when $x=5$.

---

**(2)** $\neg(\forall x\in A: P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x))$ is equivalent to $\exists x\in A:P(x)\land\neg Q(x)$.

These are not equivalent to $\forall x\in A:\neg(P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x))$. For example, if we assume the above meanings of $A$, $P$, and $Q$, then $\neg(\forall x\in A: P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x))$ is true, but $\forall x\in A: \neg(P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x))$ is false because $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ does hold for $x=28$.

---

It is not clear to me what either of these have to do with reasoning by contraposition and/or contradiction.

---

**(3)** You are right that $P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ does not in itself have a truth value until it is specified what $x$ is.

But it is *not* the case that you can therefore reinterpret it willy-nilly to mean $\forall x\in A: P(x)\Rightarrow Q(x)$ in an arbitrary context.

Some texts do unfortunately leave it to the reader to insert quantifiers that way, but that is fraught with opportunities for misunderstanding, and is a poor model for how to express mathematical relationships readably and unambiguously.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answers

Comment: 1) What I mean here when I speak about reasoning by contraposition is that, when we want to prove for example : $\forall x \in A, P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$, we have in fact one proposition here (that is true if it is true for all $x$ in $A$) and not really two propositions (even if, when we choose an $x \in A$, then we have two distincts propositions $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$). So, is it really a reasoning *by contraposition* if I choose to prove : $\forall x \in A, \neg Q(x) \Rightarrow \neg P(x)$ ? (I don't really have the feeling that it is correct because we juste have ONE proposition in fact).

Comment: Because now, if we want to prove : $(\forall x \in A, P(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall x \in A, Q(x))$, we have here two propositions thus it should be equivalent, by contraposition, to prove $(\exists x \in A, \neg Q(x)) \Rightarrow (\exists x \in A, \neg P(x))$ (this is just another example to show that it is more clear to me in that case).

Comment: 2) About reasoning by contradiction, the question is maybe more trivial : if I have to show for example that : $\forall x \in A, P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$, are we agree that I have to assume the negation : $\neg [\forall x \in A, P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)]$, and not only : $\forall x \in A, \neg[P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)]$,  in order to get my contradiction ?

Comment: @deeppinkwater (1): "Reasoning by contraposition" is a somewhat informal description of a proof strategy; it is not usually a crisp technical notion in formal proof theory. What one would do in a usual prose proof is to say something like "Let $x\in A$ be arbitrary". Then in the following paragraph we can argue under the assumption that $x$ _does_ mean something concrete, and _under that assumption_ prove $P(x)\to Q(x)$ by contraposition. After this subproof-by-contraposition is done, we tie a nice bow on it by "Since $x$ was arbitrary, we have proved $\forall x\in A:P(X)\to Q(x)$".

Comment: (IN practice these boilerplate sentences are often omitted when one is confident the reader will be able to figure out what is happening).

Comment: @deeppinkwater (2): You have two possible strategies. _Either_ assume $\neg(\forall x\in A: \cdots)$ and derive one large contradiction, _or_ start by "let $x\in A$ be arbitrary" and then prove your $P(x)\to Q(x)$ by contradiction. Thus after declaring $x$ to be arbitrary you would assume $\neg(P(x)\to Q(x))$. Note that this is not the same as having assumed $\forall x\in A: \neg(P(x)\to Q(x))$ at any point!

Comment: (These two strategies work out to needing the same _substantial_ argument to get the contradiction, so whether you justify it by the former strategy or the latter doesn't matter much. Again, in practice it is common to omit the boilerplate and just say "we prove this by contradiction". This leaves the reader to supply his favorite way of wrapping up the substantial argument in the middle).

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @deeppinkwater - I guess you should mark this answer as accepted, or ask for a further explanation if you are not completely satisfied by this answer.